# In-app purchase: changing from non-consumable to non-renewing subscription

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I have an app that currently offers non-consumable in-app purchase items. However, I'm beginning to realize the continual cost associated with providing lifetime support on a one-time purchase, therefore, I'm considering changing the in-app purchase type to non-renewing subscription. This will provide a time limit on how long I need to provide support on a single purchase.

The question is, how will this implementation affect my existing users who have already made the one-time purchase of non-consumable items, after updating the app to the new version?

You see, in the new app version, the same item is now a non-renewing subscription item, and it'll have a different product ID. If my existing users update their app to the new app version, no longer will the items they've already purchased be available in the new version. And worse, if they attempt to use the product, they will be asked to pay again (this time using non-renewing subscription).

What's the proper way to implement the change, so new purchases will be non-renewing subscriptions, while existing users can continue to use what they already bought as non-consumable items?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a thought, but taking away something a user purchased as a one-time purchase may incur user backlash.

Comment: @picciano I totally agree. That's why I want to make sure I implement the update correctly, so it works for both new and existing users.